# Is there a way around using nested media queries on Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: css, nested, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I've used nested media queries for the first time in a responsive website I've created. These help the website look as I want to in 12" laptops and portrait Ipads for instance and they work fine with all browsers except for Internet Explorer 11 (and below for that matter).

Checking on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) it specifies that nested media queries are not supported on IE11.

This is how the CSS looks like:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  @media all and (max-height: 860px) {
    /*Some code*/
  }
  @media all and (min-height: 769px) {
    /*Some Code*/
  }
}
```

What can I do or use so that these media queries will work on IE11?

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest them like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 860px) {
  /*Some code*/
}
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 769px) {
  /*Some Code*/
}
```

Or you can look into using a less compiler which would do that for you (as well as numerous other features as well).  Even with less, you should consider changing your code so that `all` isn't repeated again, like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  @media (max-height: 860px) {
    /*Some code*/
  }
  @media (min-height: 769px) {
    /*Some Code*/
  }
}
```